# erro ao conver string para float em python

Tags: string, python-3.x, float

Olá estou com um problema não estou conseguindo conveter string para float

o programa pega o preço de um jogo dps converte para string e posiciono através do caractere e não estou conseguindo converter

```
price =game.find(attrs="col search_price discounted responsive_secondr
price = str(price)
if not price[110] =="<":
    print("Sem Deconto:", price[101:109])
    print("Com Desconto:",float(price[104:109]))
else:
    print("Sem Deconto:", price[101:110])
    print("Com Desconto:",price[104:110])
```

### Resultado

File "/home/alison/Documentos/programa/steam/search_steam.py", line 57, in price
    
print("Com Desconto:",float(price[104:109]))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '36,99'

Comment: Não conheço python, mas vou dar meu chute: Tente converter `36.90` ao invés de `36,99`.

Comment: o pior que o valor do programa retorna valores com 2 virgulas e mesmo sendo 36,90 também da erro

Comment: Pois é, você tem que transformar essa virgula em um ponto, vou criar uma resposta para você ver como ficaria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como eu lhe disse no comentário, o problema é que o Python [não reconhece a virgula](https://ideone.com/9TVg2x) (,) como representação de casas decimais, somente o ponto (.), você pode reverter esta situação utilizando o `replace`, como Fábio respondeu.
Ficaria desta maneira:

```
print("Com Desconto:",float(price.replace(",",".")))
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/StzeBb).

Comment: Tem a possibilidade de usar `locale`, aí o Python reconhece a vírgula: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362256; como foi dito nas outras respostas e comentários dessa pergunta no SO internacional, isso vai mudar as configurações do `locale` corrente, e talvez isso possa gerar incongruências aqui e ali

Answer (score 1):

A String que você está lendo tem a forma '36,99' (DD,DD), isso não pode ser convertido em float por está função do python. É necessário transformar sua string para a forma 'DD.DD' (36.99) antes de fazer a conversão.

Você poderia fazer isso com funções de substituição de caracteres do python (como o [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)).