# Não foi possível converter string para float. Por quê?

Tags: python

Tentei converter alguns valores para *float*

```
self.total_PreçoCusto =   float( self.PreçoCusto) * float(self.estoque)
self.total_Preço_Venda =  float( self.Preço_Venda) *  float(self.estoque)
self.lucro =  float(self.Preço_Venda-self.PreçoCusto)
```

Mas deu erro dizendo que não foi possível converter

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 7):

Esta exceção é lançada quando a *string* que você está tentando converter não está em um formato válido. Isso acontece quando você utiliza a vírgula como separador decimal, quando a *string* é vazia ou possui caracteres não numéricos, etc.

```
>>> float('3,14159')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    float('3,14159')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 3,14159

>>> float('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    float('3,14159')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

>>> float('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    float('3,14159')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: foo
```

Se está utilizando a vírgula, você precisará antes substituir a vírgula pelo ponto.

```
>>> float('3,14159'.replace(',', '.'))
3.14159
```

- [erro ao conver string para float em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212086/5878)

Em outras situações, você precisará validar primeiro antes de converter para *float*. Se a *string* é vazia ou possui caracteres inválidos, você deverá tratar direto na fonte dos valores. Não há como definir uma solução genérica.

Fora isso, é interessante que você mantenha um padrão nas nomenclaturas das suas variáveis. Por convenção, no Python costuma-se utilizar a *snake case*, que utiliza o sublinhado, `_`, como separador de palavras. Então, ao invés de `total_PreçoCusto`, prefira `total_preço_custo`, assim como `preço_custo` e `preço_venda`.

Answer (score -3):

Remova o `ç`. PreçoCusto não é uma variável válida, isso irá causar uma série de erros. Preferencialmente use apenas letras sem acentuação, dígitos e underscore para declarar nomes de variáveis.

Além disso se `self.PrecoCusto` e `self.Preco_Venda` não são float, não tem como fazer `self.Preco_Venda - self.PrecoCusto`, teria que ser

```
self.lucro =  float(self.Preco_Venda) - float(self.PrecoCusto)
```

ou talvez o que você realmente queira seja

```
self.lucro = total_Preco_Venda - total_PrecoCusto
```

Comment: Acontece que o Python, assim como várias outras linguagens, aceita acentos, cedilha e etc nos nomes de variáveis. A final, o erro descrito na pergunta não se refere a isso.

Comment: @LipESprY na verdade o usuário nem disse qual foi o erro que ele encontrou.

Comment: Leia o título da pergunta.

Comment: olá pessoal o erro que eu encontrei foi esse :  could not convert string to float:                                                                                                                    eu mudei o código, mas continua aparecendo, ajudem, pfvr:      File "C:\exdb\pp.py", line 179, in itens_get
    self.totalcp =   float(self.cp) * float(self.estoque)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: self.totalcp =   float(self.cp) * float(self.estoque)
          self.totalsp =  float(self.sp) *  float(self.estoque)
          self.lucro =  float(self.sp ) - (self.cp)